# Is there a way to get pyPortMidi working on Win7-64?

Tags: python, pyportmidi

I'm trying to use pyPortMidi for an application that I build for OSX, win32, and win64.  I've gotten it to work on OSX and win32, but I am stuck trying to get it working on win64.

pyPortMidi is a wrapper for a C library named PortMidi, and it is available with the [PortMidi source download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/portmedia/files/portmidi/217/) as version 0.7 and from [John Harrison's site](http://alumni.media.mit.edu/~harrison/code.html) as version 0.9.  I've tried both versions with the same failure mode.

First I built PortMidi using MSVC++ 2008 Express targeted to X64.  The included test program works and is able to communicate with midi ports, so I think the PortMidi build is fine.

Next I built pyPortMidi.  For version 0.7 I had to modify the setup.py file slightly to account for the proper location of an include files (moved from ../win32 to ../pm_common) and it builds without errors.  While version 0.7 uses cython to build _pyportmidi.c, version 0.9 uses pyrex to do the same thing; to get it to work I had to use the version of pyrex installed using easy_install.  It also built without errors.

I'm able to import the library into Python, but when I make the first call it immediately crashes Python:

```
>>> import pypm
>>> pypm.Initialize()
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: python.exe
  Application Version:  0.0.0.0
  Application Timestamp:    4e70d55f
  Fault Module Name:    pypm.pyd
  Fault Module Version: 0.0.0.0
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4f8383fc
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000000000009000
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0f1f
  Additional Information 2: 0f1f1099a7fb7a2294c21b52e8fe20f2
  Additional Information 3: 07a8
  Additional Information 4: 07a8c952d5efd7a04abd16111aad6ab0
```

Has anyone gotten pyPortMidi running on X64?  Any suggestions as to how I could debug this issue?

Comment: You may want to look at this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27737264/installing-pygame-on-64-bit-windows-7-and-64-bit-python-2-7) for a solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An updated pypm module is available as [pygame.pypm](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/01b2cb16dc17/src/pypm.pyx). Using win-amd64-py2.7 binaries from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame the following works:

```
>>> from pygame import pypm
>>> pypm.Initialize()
```

Comment: That works.  I'll have to take a look at what changed to satisfy my curiosity.  Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I hope more people find this answer. Pygame was a small easy download and changing pyportmidi's test script (from it's download, not pygame's) to this line gets it working right away. It was the simplest solution for getting some midi data into python and suited my needs quite well.