# Installing Pygame on 64-bit Windows 7 and 64-bit Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, installation-package

The title says it all. I do see similar questions, someone suggested about http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame, but all the pygame downloadable files are in .whl format which I have no idea how to run on Windows 7. I tried "cd [directory] > pip install [filename]" without success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked from me (Windows 7, python 2.7, 64 bit):

```
pip install C:/Users/ujjwal.karn/Downloads/pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

I downloaded the file `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl` from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame as well.

In general, `whl` files are installed with `pip`:

```
pip install whatever.whl
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I get pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. I don't know if that's because of the AMD portion or what.

Answer (score 2):

Open the .whl file through WinRar and just extract the contents(you will find 3 folders) into your Python folder.
For example : if you had installed python 2.7.3 in C:, then your directory to extract will be C:\Python27

Answer (score 0):

You are doing right. Please just check python command it should display win64

```
C:>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:43:06) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (In
tel)] on win64 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

if output is win32 install pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win32.whl