# Having trouble installing pygame for python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, pygame, package

I am using windows 8.1 64 bit, and after installing the pip tool i tried to install pygame. I used the pip install command and i get the following error:

```
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

I'm not sure what to do to install it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28150762/3166303

Comment: @leeor  i used this command platform.architecture () and i get the following tuple: ('64bit', 'WindowsPE') which probably means that i am indeed using a 64 bit version of python 3.5 . I tried including the full path too but i keep getting the same error –

Comment: what does the architecture say in the output for python? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30242733/3166303

Comment: the following command : C:>python gives no output whatsoever. This is what happens: C:\Users\Vlassis>C:>python (i press enter and then it moves to the next line) C:\Users\Vlassis> like nothing has happened.

Comment: Not sure if this would help but I think it's possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107123/cannot-install-numpy-from-wheel-format